# I Have Crash Error when I Clicked Button; The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have this error:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first.

When I clicked `buildNot.setPosiviteButton`.
Help me please, thanks guys!
This is my Java source code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnDersEkle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDersEkle);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        etDers = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        etNot = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        //Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        build.setTitle("Ders Ekle");
        build.setView(etDers);
        //Dialog Not
        final AlertDialog.Builder buildNot = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        buildNot.setTitle("Not Ekle");
        buildNot.setView(etNot);

        build.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                adapter.add(etDers.getText().toString());
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alertDers = build.create();

        buildNot.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 adapter = (ArrayAdapter ) list.getAdapter();
                  String item = (String) list.getSelectedItem();
                  int position = list.getSelectedItemPosition();
                  item += "YourText";
                  adapter.insert(item, position);
                  dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alertNot = buildNot.create();
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                alertNot.show();
            }
        });
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnDersEkle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDers.show();

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: on which line an exception is thrown?

Comment: usually, stacktrace shows you method on which exeption is thrown, and line number.

Comment: @FurkanKELES kindly share the stacktrace/Logcat in your post. It will help us quickly answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That is because nothing is selected.

`list.getSelectedItemPosition()` will always return -1.

"Click" and "select" are separate things. "Select" in a ListView is done via the pointing device (D-pad, trackball, arrow keys, etc.).

`list.getSelectedItemPosition()` will always return -1 if you are not using D-pad, trackball or arrow keys.

You should store the `position` in `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` as a class member and access it in `buildNot.setPositiveButton` `onClick`.

Coding below, where `mPosition` is a class member of your class.

```
buildNot.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        adapter = (ArrayAdapter ) list.getAdapter();
        String item = (String) adapter.getItem(mPosition);
        item += "YourText";
        adapter.insert(item, mPosition);
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
```

---

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        mPosition = position;
        alertNot.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I did but when i add new text return "null" to me android emulator screen. http://postimg.org/image/qet9k5ffn/

Comment: The same to  `getSelectedItem `. `getSelectedItem` depends on `getSelectedItemPosition`. It will return null since nothing is selected. Using `Adapter.getItem(position)` instead.

Comment: Main code is added to the end of my answer. `mPosition` is a class member of your activity which could be added above the line of `onCreate`

Comment: One quesition more ^^ How i update clicked text? I clicked text and input text with editText and my text will update. How i do this?

Comment: buildNot.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                adapter = (ArrayAdapter ) list.getAdapter();
                String item = etNot.getText().toString();
                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(mPosition));
                adapter.insert(item, mPosition);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

Comment: My friend so sorry but i want prevoius text dont remove. I want new text add to near my first text. like this : item +=etNot.getText().toString();. Can you help me again? :(

Comment: buildNot.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            adapter = (ArrayAdapter ) list.getAdapter();
            String item = adapter.getItem(mPosition);
            item += etNot.getText().toString();
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(mPosition));
            adapter.insert(item, mPosition);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76230/discussion-between-small-archer-and-furkan-keles).

Answer (score 1):

Try change your code like below, maybe help

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

int posmy;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainlistnew);


        Button btnDersEkle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDersEkle);

        final ListView list = getListView();
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);


        final EditText etDers = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        final EditText etNot = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        //Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        build.setTitle("Ders Ekle");
        build.setView(etDers);

        //Dialog Not
        final AlertDialog.Builder buildNot = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        buildNot.setTitle("Not Ekle");
        buildNot.setView(etNot);

        build.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                adapter.add(etDers.getText().toString());
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alertDers = build.create();

        buildNot.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  //adapter = (ArrayAdapter ) list.getAdapter();
                  //String item = (String) list.getSelectedItem();
                  //int position = list.getSelectedItemPosition();
                  int position=posmy;
                  String item = "YourText" + etNot.getText().toString();
                  adapter.insert(item, position);
                  dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alertNot = buildNot.create();


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                posmy=position;
                alertNot.show();
            }
        });

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnDersEkle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDers.show();

            }
        });

}



}
```